# How to get certain data from database based on primary key from select option?

Tags: php, php-7.2

i have database with table like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_pangkat` (
  `Id_pangkat` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Nama_jabatan` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Besar_gaji` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id_pangkat`)
INSERT INTO `tb_pangkat` VALUES (1,'Penasehat',2000000),(2,'Pengurus',2000000),(3,'Pengawas',2000000),(4,'Kasi Umum',1000000),(5,'Kasi Pengawas',1000000),(6,'Kasi Kredit',1000000),(7,'Kasi Keuangan',1000000),(8,'Kasi Pengembangan Bisnis',1000000);
```

and i have form php like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Pangkat</label>
            <div>
                <select name="pangkat" class="form-control col-sm-10">
                  <option value="">Pilih Pangkat</option>
                  <?php
                    include "koneksi.php";                
                    $tampil = mysqli_query($mysqli, "select * from tb_pangkat");
                    $no = 1;
                    while($hasil = mysqli_fetch_array($tampil)){
                  ?>
              <option value="<?php echo $hasil['Id_pangkat']; ?>">
                  <?php echo $hasil['Nama_jabatan']; ?>
              </option>
              <?php } ?>
              </select> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Gaji</label>
            <input type="number" name="gaji" class="form-control" placeholder="Masukan Gaji" value="<?php echo $hasil['Id_pangkat']; ?>" required readonly>            
          </div>
```

form pangkat will take the Id_pangkat and display the Nama_jabatan, then I want form gaji to display the value from the Besar_gaji based on the selected Id_pangkat, how do I do that?

Comment: You could use AJAX for that - when the selection in the dropdown changes, send an AJAX request to the server containing the selected ID. PHP on the server can run a query to select the specific value from the row, an return it. javascript then displays it in the correct box. It's not clear where you're stuck with this process? What have you researched / tried so far? This is all fairly standard pieces of functionality. Put them all together to make your solution.

Comment: @ADyson can it be done without ajax? because I'm still a beginner and don't really understand ajax, for example, can it be manipulated in the models file?

Comment: You can do it without AJAX by just posting back a form every time a selection is made. It's just not as good as a user experience. But yes if you're a beginner it would be good not to complicate things